Compile error when watcher definition how can i fix it?
When i want to create below watcher definition, i get compile error. Is there any idea why i get compile error and how can i fix it ?
To be more clearly, i want to check if total hits > 10, if the condition is met then critical alert should post otherwise normal alert should post (to understand that problem is fixed)
{
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "10m"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
        "indices": [
          "mfp.application-log*"
        ],
        "rest_total_hits_as_int": true,
        "body": {
          "size": 0,
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "service.keyword": {
                      "value": "RL1C971D"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "level.keyword": {
                      "value": "ERROR"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "range": {
                    "timestamp": {
                      "gt": "now-60m"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              "boost": 1
            }
          },
          "aggs": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "script": {
      "source": "def previousState = ctx.metadata.previous_state ?: 'normal'; def currentTotal = ctx.payload.hits.total; if (currentTotal >= 10 && previousState == 'normal'){ctx.metadata.previous_state = 'critical'; return 'critical';} else if (currentTotal < 10 && previousState == 'critical') { ctx.metadata.previous_state = 'normal'; return 'normal'; } else { return 'none';}"
    }
  },
  "actions": {
    "my_webhook": {
      "condition":{
        "script":{
          "source": "ctx.payload.result == 'critical'"
        }
      },
      "webhook": {
        "scheme": "http",
        "host": "x",
        "port": 3,
        "method": "post",
        "path": "demo.com",
        "params": {},
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        "body": "<BSMConnectorEvent><alertname>demoAlarm</alertname><domain>demo</domain><severity>Major</severity><relatedCI>demo</relatedCI><alertdetails> mail ile bilgi verilmelidir. Match count: {{ctx.payload.hits.total}}</alertdetails></BSMConnectorEvent>"
      }
    },
    "my_webhook2":{
      "condition":{
        "script":{
          "source": "ctx.payload.result == 'normal'"
        }
      },
       "webhook": {
        "scheme": "http",
        "host": "demo.com",
        "port": 3,
        "method": "post",
        "path": "x",
        "params": {},
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        "body": "<BSMConnectorEvent><alertname>demo Alarm</alertname><domain>OC</domain><severity>Clear</severity><relatedCI>Kullandırım Değerlendirme İşlemleri Erişilebilirlik KPI</relatedCI><alertdetails>bilgi verilmelidir. Match count: {{ctx.payload.hits.total}}</alertdetails></BSMConnectorEvent>"
      }
    }
  }
}

